# Report in ASP.Net - code or transformation?

Tags: asp.net, xml, xslt, report

So I have to write a HTML report that pulls information from various XML sources. I have the choice of using XSLT to generate the report or just write it in ASPX by serializing the XMLs into C# objects and using these objects to fill in the information in the aspx page.

Which alternative would be better in terms of development time and performance?

Comment: Interesting question, XSLT's great and purpose built for the job BUT can be thorny with a big learning curve. I guess it depends on how comfortable you are with either technology as that would have a large baring on development times. Interesting question though!

Comment: Technically I am very comfortable with either alternative. It feels that XSLT would be a cleaner and elegant solution but using code was raised as possibly better/easier.

Comment: One question you need to ask yourself and this will answer your question... Will you re-use the C# objects anywhere else?  If not, well I think it's pretty obvious choice.

Comment: @Steve -  Very unlikely. Plus we don't have real XSDs for the XML we are reading from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, a big part of the decision is whether the structure of the XML sources will change very often or if I will need to add/remove XML sources. With XSLT, you can just make the changes without having to recompile your code.